# How to sync client and server socket python Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, sockets

I have the following sending frames from the client to server inside a docker container. When I run the below code the client doesn't wait for the server and sends starting the data. Help is highly appreciated on how to solve this issue.

Streamer.py

```
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://192.168.56.103:5555')
videoFile = "D:/testing.mp4"
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)  
while True:
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()  
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))  
    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)
```

Viewer.py

```
model = VGG19( weights="imagenet" )
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))
while True:
    frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
    img = base64.b64decode(frame)
    npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    source = cv2.imdecode( npimg, 1 )
    frame=cv2.resize(source,(224,224)).astype("float32")
    image = img_to_array( source)
    image = image.reshape( (1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 
    image.shape[2]) )
    image = preprocess_input( image )
    preds = model.predict(image)
```

The code works fine I am able to receive the complete frames but at the end I receive the below error.
Error

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))  # resize the frame
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion 
failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Thanks, help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the while loop in case that `.read()` is empty.
So you have to add an `if` statement here:

```
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://192.168.56.103:5555')
videoFile = "D:/testing.mp4"
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)  
while True:
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()
    if not grabbed:
        break
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))  
    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)
```

Actually I have no test data from you so it can be possible that you have to check frame if it is empty or not. If it's true you have to break the while loop to avoid running in the error.

Another possible way to handle this is to capture the error with a try and except statement:

```
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://192.168.56.103:5555')
videoFile = "D:/testing.mp4"
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)  
while True:
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()
    try:
         frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
    except cv2.error:
         break
    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)
```